# artist-mode copy a square?

Tags: artist-mode

When using artist-mode I often find I want to create several equally sized boxes for a diagram.

Is there an easy way I can copy an existing shape on my page and drag it out to a new place?

*Or a way to make consistently sized rectangles instead of drag and drop.*

Comment: Take a look at the section about rectangles in mode's help. Try typing `F1 m` and searching for "rectangles".

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIuX87Xo8Fc).  It teaches how to copy and do other useful stuff in artist mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:
In artist-mode click `middle mouse button` and from that appearing popup menu select `edit` -> `copy`. Then draw an rectangle around your existing shape to copy it.
After this select `paste` from that same popup menu. Then, when you `left click` with your mouse, you will paste the copied rectangle at point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the instructions I found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangle-Registers.html), but it doesn't copy exactly as expected:

[image]

I'm running the first command to copy to register `r`. as soon as I create the first rectangle with my cursor on the bottom right corner:

```
C-x r r r
```

I then run `C-x r i r` but the right side where my cursor is doesn't get copied.

Comment: I guess you just haven't selected that border. Make sure the rectangle you want to copy is highlighted in its entirety.